# Read JavaScript values HtmlAgility Pack

Tags: c#, wpf, automated-tests, desktop-application

Can we read the value being written by `document.Write(some variable)` ,basically there is a variable dynamic which gets value by a script.so can we know what value is there in this variable by Html agility pack if there are any other way of doing that please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

No, Html Agility pack is a parser and that can only look at the static text of the document.

What you need, is to have the javascript evaluated before you look at the page state. This is more like browser automation.

Take look at [Watin](http://watin.org/), I think that does what you want.